# PostgreSQL database explorer

Tags: windows, ide, postgresql

I'm looking for a nice visual explorer for PostgreSQL.

I found [DataGrip](https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/) by JetBrains. The issue is the price is high, at least for me.

I would like to have another explorer, which is comfortable, visually speaking and with a lower price. The explorer has to be for Windows (7 and onward). But it has to be an IDE too, because I'm developing SQL queries.

Comment: What features do you need? Is a simple database browser enough? The "D" in "IDE" means "Development", what kind of development do you need the tool to allow you to do?

Comment: Hi @NicolasRaoul, I need the same thing as I have with SqlServer Management Studio but for postgres (e.g having a tree with the referencing of the objects in the db, be able to write queries that will put the correct syntax and the correct object names).

Comment: @AndyK Please edit your Question with further information rather than post as comments.

Answer (score 4):

I use [pgAdmin](https://pgadmin.org/) for this.

It meets your requirements as far as I can tell:

- Works with Windows 7 and onwards
- Has a visual tree tree with the referencing of the objects in the db
- Able to write queries

Comment: Hi @ryan-weaver nice! I need to have a look. Thanks.

Comment: Distributions of Postgres commonly bundle pgAdmin. So you may already have it. Beware that the many-years-old well-worn edition of pgAdmin (QT-based C app) is being replaced with an all-new dual-purpose web app/desktop app edition, with all-new code base.

Answer (score 1):

pgAdmin is the best option because it is built for PostgreSQL only.

I am using pgAdmin and [Database .NET](http://fishcodelib.com/database.htm), Database .NET is my favorite since it has many good features which pgAdmin doesn't. It is very lightweight (free and commercial versions are available) and portable.You can connect many databases with this.

[image]